# Showing the existence of $\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\ln (x)\, dx$ and calculating it

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

> Show that the integral $$\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\log (x)\, dx$$ exists and calculate that.

To calculate that integral I have done the following :

We substitute $z=\ln (x) \Rightarrow x=e^z$.

When $x=0$ then $z=-\infty$

When $x=1$ then $z=0$

We have that $\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow dx=xdz=e^zdz$

Then we get $$\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\ln (x)\, dx=\int_{-\infty}^0\sqrt{e^z}z\, e^zdz=\int_{-\infty}^0e^{z/3}z\, dz$$

Is that the correct way to calculate the integral?

At the beginning where we have to show the existence, do we show that just by calculating the integral or is there also an other way to show the existence?

Comment: Where have you calculated the integral -- you still need to show $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{z/3}zdx$ exists, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it simpler using $x=t^2$

$$I=\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\log (x)\, dx=4\int_0^1 t^2\log(t) \,dt$$ and we know that $\lim_{t\to 0} \, t\log(t)=0$.

Now, one integration by parts to obtain the result.

Comment: This is the simplest and most effective way in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

By using this substitution, you are using the fact that the map $x \mapsto e^x$ is differentiable with a continuous derivative.

But no, this is not the most efficient way. You may use integration by parts immediately here. The reason is that product of the integral of $\sqrt x$ and the derivative of $\log x$ is readily integrable: $x^{3/2} \cdot \frac 1 x = x^{1/2}$.

You may read about the two topics in depth here: [Integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)
, and [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Comment: Also the limit of $x^{3/2}\log x,$ when $x\to 0^+,$ exists (and is equal $0$)

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Then we get $$\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\log (x)\, dx=\int_{-\infty}^0\sqrt{e^z}z\, e^zdz=\int_{-\infty}^0e^{z/3}z\, dz$$

The last step should be

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^0e^{\frac{3}2z}z\, dz$$
you can define: $z=-\frac{2}3u$

$$I=-\frac{4}9\int_0^\infty ue^{-u}du=-\frac{4}9\Gamma(2)=-\frac{4}9$$

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Comment: you are most welcome :) @MaryStar

Answer (score 1):

One way to show just existence is as follows:

Note that $\ln(0) = -\infty$ so we need to show that

$$\lim_{c \to 0^+} \int_c^1 \sqrt{x}\ln(x)dx\;\;\text{exists}$$

We can use the fact that $\sqrt{x},\ln(x)$ are continuous on $(0,1]$, so their [product is continuous](https://portal.tpu.ru/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Sites/English_sites/calculus/2_ContinuityProp_f.htm) on $(0,1]$

Let $0<a<1$, then by the [mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals):

$$\exists k \in (a,1]: \sqrt{k}\ln(k) = \frac{1}{1-a}\int_a^1 \sqrt{x}\ln(x)dx$$

So in the case where $a>0$ we know the integral exists.

Now we need to show that $\sqrt{x}\ln(x)$ is right-continuous at $x=0$.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sqrt{x}\ln(x) = 0\cdot -\infty \implies \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{-\frac12}} =  \frac{-\infty}{-\infty}$$
$$ \stackrel{\text{L'Hopital}}{\implies} \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac12 x^{-\frac32}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{-\frac12 x^{\frac32}}{x} = -\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac12 x^{\frac12} = 0$$

So it $\sqrt{x}\ln(x)$ is (right)-continuous on $[0,1]$ so by above the integral exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar you’re welcome :-)